# Essential extension.

Tags: homological-algebra

I'm trying to solve this question. My TA told me that it was *easy* and the information/assumption given is useless.

**Question**

We have the following inclusions of $R$-modules $M\subseteq N \subseteq L$

> Prove that if N and L are both essential extensions of M, then L is
>   also an essential extension of N.

I have tried to solve it using his method: "Use the inclusion function".

Okay so I choose the injective function $i:N \hookrightarrow L$ given by the inclusion. Then I need to show, according to the defintion, that if I choose $S\subseteq L$ then $S\cap i(N) = S\cap N \neq \lbrace 0 \rbrace$.

So I need to show that there exists no submodule $S$ in $L$ such that $S \subseteq L-N$. 
How do I proceed with this technique?

Answer (score 1):

You have to show, that for every submodule $S \subset L$ with $S \cap N = \{0\}$ it follows that $S = \{0\}$.

So let  $S \subset L$ be a a submodule with $S \cap N = \{0\}$. Then $$\{0\} = (S \cap N) \cap M = S \cap (N \cap M) =S \cap M,$$ from what follows that $S$ must be $\{0\}$, since $L$ is an essential extension of $M$.

Hope this is the right argument. We didn't need that $N$ is an essential extension of $M$ though.

Comment: Since $L$ is an essential extension of $M$ we know that there exists an injective function $\alpha: M \rightarrow L$ such that for each $S\subset L$ we have $S\cap \alpha(M)$. It appears to me that you use that the injective function in this case is the inclusion such that $\alpha ( M ) = M$ ?